# Check if a column's value exist in previous columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, isin

I have a dataframe as below,

```
d = {'Person1': ['Apple', 'Mango'], 'Person2': ['Orange', 'Apple'],  'Person3': ['Orange', 'Apple'], 'Person4': ['Orange', 'Apple'], 'Person5': ['Watermelon', 'Mango']}

df1= pd.DataFrame(data= d)

    Person1 Person2 Person3 Person4 Person5

0    Apple  Orange  Orange  Orange  Watermelon

1    Mango   Apple  Apple   Apple   Mango
```

I want to check if a person has the same fruit and keep the value if no match is found,

```
     Person1 Person2 Person3 Person4 Person5

 0   Apple   Orange  True    True    Watermelon

 1    Mango   Apple  True    True    True
```

Comment: Do you want to compare only Person2 with Person3? You can get your wanted output with `df1['Person3'] = df1['Person3'].eq(df1['Person2'])` but I dubt that this is the final result.

Comment: I want to check for every column, if a value of a column exists in any of the previous columns then return the value as true otherwise keep the same value.

Comment: Could you please extend your example? Right now I don't know the wanted oupout.

Comment: Sure, I have extended my example. Please let me know if it is still not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little help of `numpy` you can do:

```
import numpy as np

for i in range(len(df1)):
        df1.iloc[i, :] = np.where(df1.iloc[i, :].duplicated() == False, df1.iloc[i, :], True)
```

The output will be:

```
  Person1 Person2 Person3 Person4     Person5
0   Apple  Orange    True    True  Watermelon
1   Mango   Apple    True    True        True
```

Comment: can you also let me know if I need to check this for only one case. For example,  for Apple.

Comment: One way of doing this is add your constraints into the `np.where`, like this:
`df1.iloc[i, :] = np.where((df1.iloc[i, :].duplicated()) & (df1.iloc[i, :] == 'Apple') == False, df1.iloc[i, :], True)`